# Guardar retorno dos campos em variáveis em python

Tags: mysql, python

Fiz uma consulta em mysql com python e mostro o resultado:

```
cursor = db.cursor()    
cursor.execute("SELECT Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes ON centrodb.utentes.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")    
myresult = cursor.fetchone()    
print(myresult)
```

Em vez do print, pretendo guardar em variáveis cada coluna retornada na consulta no python

Comment: Qual é a saída do `print`? Que tipo é o objeto `myresult`? Um dicionário?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, o print foi mesmo só para imprimir a linha como teste. Agora a minha dúvida é como guardo os dados retornados de cada coluna em variáveis

Comment: E quanto ao tipo do objeto? É um dicionário mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html), o retorno de `fetchone` será uma tupla com os valores retornados do banco de dados. Assim, para criar variáveis, você pode fazer a desconstrução da tupla:

```
dias, hora_consulta, hora_saida, ... = myresult
```

Assim, cada valor da tupla será armazenada na respectiva variável.